# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create a spam command for my friend ,there is my code :

```js
    var msgSplit = message.content.split(" ")
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefixe+"spam"))
    {
        if(message.author.id == '389075094045196328')
        {
            var message = msgSplit[1]
            message.channel.send("1")
        }
    }
```

And i got this problem : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined`
if i put this code ,i don't get any problem :

```js
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefixe+"spam"))
    {
        if(message.author.id == '389075094045196328')
        {
            message.channel.send("1")
        }
    }
```

if you have an idee pls tell me (Sorry for my bad english :/)

Answer (score 0):

If `message.content` does not contain any spaces then `msgSplit[1]` would be `undefined` because you will end up with `msgSplit` array only with 1 element only.

```js
const test = '111'
const splittedTest = test.split(' ')
console.log(splittedTest[0]) // 111
console.log(splittedTest[1]) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining `message` with the assignment of `msgSplit[1]` and so 'channel' no longer exists on that object. If you need to get the value from the index [1] and send it with the message, just reference that in your send.

```
    var msgSplit = message.content.split(" ")
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefixe+"spam"))
    {
        if(message.author.id == '389075094045196328')
        {
            message.channel.send(msgSplit[1])
        }
    }
```

Comment: This could lead to an error of msgSplit[1] being undefined but a quick check of the array length before calling send would cover that.